# JSF update page components using ajax after loading a cached page

Tags: ajax, jsf, caching, primefaces

I am working on a website using JSF and Primefaces.

We have recently enabled mod_cache on our Apache reverse proxy, which works fine for pages that are completely static and are displayed exactly the same way for each user. However, we want to enable cache on other pages, where if the user is logged in his name is displayed in the navbar.

The ideal behaviour that I would like to achieve:

1. Initially the page doesn't have any user data (so it can be cached and displayed to other users)
2. AJAX request is sent to the backend to find out if the user is logged and his name if he is
3. Put the data on the page using javascript

Even though the idea doesn't seem difficult, I have found it quite difficult to put in practice. For example, when I call a hidden button to send an action request I see the data being loaded in the backend, however in the frontend javascript logging it is not always there.

What would be the best way to achieve the behaviour that I would like?

What I've tried:

```
                   <script>
                        window.onload = function() {
                            console.log("Request navbar update");
                            document.getElementById('hidden:link').onclick();
                        }
                    </script>

                    <h:panelGroup id="navbarResponseHandlerPanel">
                    <script>
                        function navbarResponseHandler(){
                                $('#dropdown-logged-out').toggle(#{currentUserNavbarBean.baseUser eq null});
                                $('#dropdown-logged-in').toggle(#{currentUserNavbarBean.baseUser ne null});
                                $('.dropdown-username').text('#{currentUserNavbarBean.baseUser.displayName}');
                                console.log('#{currentUserNavbarBean.baseUser.displayName}');
                        }
                    </script>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <h:form id="hidden" style="display:none">
                        <p:commandButton id="link" action="#{currentUserNavbarBean.loadUser()}" update=":navbarResponseHandlerPanel" oncomplete="navbarResponseHandler()" />
                     </h:form>
```

(currentUserNavbarBean.loadUser() sets the baseUser field from a session bean. It didn't seem to work well with RequestScope. I might try setting it to SessionScope, but then I will have to reset it after the page is rendered, so if user goes to another page, the user name will not get filled in straightaway and doesn't get cached)

Comment: I've ended up making a servlet which gets the current user using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() and sends it via JSON, which is then called by jQuery ajax.